# Checking Palindrome text, with ignored punctuation marks, spaces and case

Tags: python, python-3.x

Homework exercise:
Checking whether a text is a palindrome should also ignore punctuation, spaces and case. For example, "Rise to vote, sir." is also a palindrome but our current program doesn't say it is. Can you improve the above program to recognize this palindrome?

origin code:

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]
def is_palindrome(text):
    return text == reverse(text)

something = input('Enter text: ') 

if (is_palindrome(something)):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome") 
else:
    print("No, it is not a palindrome")
```

my try:

```
import re

def reverse(text):
    global words
    words = text.split()
    return words[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    return words==reverse(text)

something = input('Enter text: ')
if (is_palindrome(something)):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome")
else:
    print("No, it is not a palindrome")
```

Error:

```
Enter text: jfldj
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/Problem Solving/user_input.py", line 13, in <module>
print("Yes, it is a palindrome")
File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/Problem Solving/user_input.py", line 10, in is_palindrome

NameError: name 'words' is not defined
```

How should I change my code?

Latest code:

```
import string

def remove_punctuations(word):
    return "".join(i.lower() for i in word if i not in string.ascii_letters)

def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    text = remove_punctuations(text)
    return text == reverse(text)

something = input('Enter text: ')
if (is_palindrome(something)):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome"
else:
    print("No, it is not a palindrome")
```

No matter what I input, output is Yes.

```
Enter text: hggjkgkkkk
Yes, it is a palindrome
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You don't need globals for this. Besides, you're reversing the words, not the letters.

Comment: Why are you defining a `global` variable ?

Comment: I just begin studying python. Could you please tell me how to  ignore punctuation, spaces and case in this case?

Comment: To explain the original error. When you state that a variable is global, Python expects it to already exist even if it's just been declared as empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore the punctuations, spaces and case of the given text you need to define a function `remove_punctuations()` which takes a word as parameter and returns a word with all lower case characters, remove punctuation marks and removed spaces.

To remove the unwanted characters we need to iterate over the given text, if the current character falls in `strings.ascii_letters` , then generate the character converting it to lower caps using `str.lower()` method. Finally using `"".join()` method to concatenate the generated `str` elements.

```
import string

def remove_punctuations(word):
    return "".join(i.lower() for i in word if i in string.ascii_letters)

def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]

def is_palindrome(text):
    text = remove_punctuations(text)
    return text==reverse(text)

something = "Rise to vote, sir."

if (is_palindrome(something)):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome")
else:
    print("No, it is not a palindrome")
```

Comment: I upvoted you, because overall this is a good answer, but I have two suggestions that would improve the program. 0) Instead of removing characters in `string.punctuation`, *keep* characters that are in `string.ascii_letters`.  That way if something unexpected appears, such as a Unicode punctuation character, the program will still work.  1) Instead of a list comprehension inside `str.join()` inside `remove_punctuation()`, use a generator expression.  To do that, simply remove the `[` and `]` around the list comprehension.

Comment: @ZdaR, Could u please have a look. What's wrong with my latest code?

Comment: @zoe_tang You have some unmatched brackets. Make sure you always pair an open bracket with a close one.

Comment: @zoe_tang You haven't copied the exact code of mine , in the  `remove_punctuations()` function you have used `if i not in ` whereas I had used `if i in`, this difference of not would change the whole logic . this snippet is working fine for my cases

Answer (score 2):

Since the hint says to use a tuple with forbidden punctuation marks, I created the following variant:

```
forbidden = (' ', ',', "'", '?', '!', '.', '’')


def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]


def cleaning(text):
    clean_text = ''
    for item in text:
        if item not in forbidden:
            clean_text += item
    return clean_text


def is_palindrome(text):
    lower_text = cleaning(text.lower())
    return lower_text == reverse(lower_text)


example = input('Enter something: ')
if is_palindrome(example):
    print("Yes, it is a palindrome")
else:
    print("No, it is not a palindrome")
```

The cleaning function checks each character for belonging to a tuple of forbidden characters, if not, then concatenates it to the clean_text string

Answer (score 1):

I started studying for python 2 days before so that is what i come up with.
It is not so much advanced but works like a charm. :D
It is pretty straight forward what i do there. I just make a tuple with the "legal" letters (abc=). Then I define a function that 1st change all letters to lower case and then checks every character in the string with the "legal" letters. Then after this "filtering" the rawtext contains only the "legal" ones. Then the 2nd function just reverses the results of the 1st one. Compare and da da..!

```
# Palindrome recognize
abc='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
def rawtext(text):
    rawtext=''
    text=text.lower()
    for j in text[::1]:
        for i in abc[::1]:        
            if j==i:                
                rawtext=rawtext+j
    return rawtext

def reverse(text):
    rev= rawtext(text)[::-1]   
    return rev

text=str(input('Write  text:'))

if reverse(text)==rawtext:
    print('The text is palindrome')
else:
    print('The text is not a palindrome')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def is_palindrome(s):
    l = len(s)
    fi = (i for i in xrange(l) if s[i].isalpha())
    bi = (i for i in xrange(l-1, -1, -1) if s[i].isalpha())
    for f, b in izip_longest(fi, bi):
        if f >= b: return True
        if s[f].lower() != s[b].lower(): return False
    return True
```

Hope that helps